# How to enable `--embed` with cythonize?

Tags: python, cython

When calling `cython` on the command line, it's possible to tell it to create a `int main()` method that embeds the Python interpreter:

```
$ cython --embed main.pyx
$ grep 'int main' main.c
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
```

However, when you `import Cython` directly, e.g. from a `distutils` `setup.py` script, the `embed` option seems to be ignored:

```
$ python3
>>> from Cython.Compiler import Options
>>> Options.embed = True
>>> from Cython.Build import cythonize
>>> cythonize('main.pyx')
[1/1] Cythonizing main.pyx
>>>
$ grep 'int main' main.c
$
```

What is it that I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I figured it out from Cython's sources.

It looks like Cython expects a specific value for `Options.embed`:

```
Options.embed = "main"
```

Comment: Ok, but what does this even mean?  Where does `Options.embed="main"` go?

Comment: When calling Cython from a Python build script, before calling `cythonize` from `from Cython.Build import cythonize`, `from Cython.Compiler import Options` and set the option. Example: https://github.com/SFTtech/openage/blob/100a195e9351257b4dff709c38ed5e7962f56d07/buildsystem/cythonize.py#L165