# Cython --embed flag in setup.py

Tags: python, cython, python-3.5

I am starting to compile my Python 3 project with Cython, and I would like to know if it's possible to reduce my current compile time workflow to a single instruction.

This is my setup.py as of now:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize

extensions = [
    Extension("v", ["version.py"]),
    Extension("*", ["lib/*.py"])
]

setup(
    name = "MyFirst App",
    ext_modules = cythonize(extensions),
)
```

And this is what I run from shell to obtain my executables:

```
python3 setup.py build_ext --inplace
cython3 --embed -o main.c main.py
gcc -Os -I /usr/include/python3.5m -o main main.c -lpython3.5m -lpthread -lm -lutil -ldl
```

This whole process works just fine, I'd like to know if there is a way to also embed the last two instruction in the setup.py script.

Thank you

Comment: Don't think the answer is good enough to justify flagging as a duplicate, but it might be useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31307169/how-to-enable-embed-with-cythonize

Comment: Hi @DavidW. I tried that route, and I can get a compilable main .c file. However, the cythonize method still produces a non-standalone main.so file. If I compile the produced main.c it works. I'm dashing through the docs, but I don't know what I'm missing...

Comment: @Guerriky Same issue.

Comment: I only know how to do this on windows. but you can put all of your cmd instructions in a .bat file and than just call that file

Comment: create a bash file with your 3 commands ?

Comment: You can use the subprocess module (https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) to execute shell commands.

Answer (score 1):

Start off with checking out [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/configfile.html) for the utility you're using.  If there are complicated arguments, there is probably a config file.

This should tidy up your first command:

```
# setup.cfg
[build_ext]
inplace=1
```

I don't see anything in the docs about a post-build step, and I wouldn't really expect this process to execute shell commands afterwards. `build_ext` is for building python. `make` is very available and usual for building C binaries.

Add a `Makefile` to your project.  If you have `gcc`installed, you likely have `make` already:

```
# Makefile (lines need to start with tab)

compile:
    python3 setup.py build_ext --inplace
    cython3 --embed -o main.c main.py
    gcc -Os -I /usr/include/python3.5m -o main main.c -lpython3.5m -lpthread -lm -lutil -ldl
```

Now you can just type `make` or `make compile` to get the desired affect.