# Cython embed on Windows

Tags: python, windows, cython, setuptools, distutils

I have read [How to enable `--embed` with cythonize?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31307169/how-to-enable-embed-with-cythonize) and [Cython --embed flag in setup.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46824143/cython-embed-flag-in-setup-py) but this method does not work on Windows. Let's say we have:

```
# app.py
print("hello")
```

```
# build.py
import setuptools   # allows us to avoid calling vcvarsall.bat, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/53172602/
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize
from Cython.Compiler import Options
Options.embed = "main"
setup(ext_modules=cythonize(r'app.py', build_dir="release"), script_args=['build'], options={'build': {'build_lib': 'release'}})
```

Running this `build.py` script on Python 3.8 for Windows does not produce an `app.exe` file like it would with the command line command:

```
cython app.py --embed
```

Instead, it produces a `.pyd` file.

**How to use `cythonize` + `embed` from a Python script, producing a .exe, on Windows?**

Comment: I take it you tried to add a `if __name__ == '__main__':` statement inside the .py file.  I always just compile Cython as PYDs and haven't tried the embed option before.  But since the `Options.embed = "main"` refers to something not in the .py file, it could be the issue.

Comment: @Matt If I'm correct, it sadly doesn't solve the problem here. It seems here that there is a Cython bug: `Options.embed = "main"` is not used on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved: in fact the problem did not come from `cythonize` itself, but from the fact `distutils.core.setup(...)` is configured to compile+link into a .pyd instead of a .exe.

Here is the solution:

```
from distutils._msvccompiler import MSVCCompiler    # "from distutils.msvccompiler" did not work for me!
from Cython.Compiler import Options
Options.embed = "main"
cythonize(r'src\app.py', build_dir="build")

compiler = MSVCCompiler()
compiler.compile([r"build\src\app.c"], include_dirs=["C:/Python38/include"])
compiler.link_executable([r"build\src\app.obj"], "app", libraries=["python38"], library_dirs=["C:/Python38/libs"], output_dir="release", extra_preargs=["/NOIMPLIB", "/NOEXP"])
```

The .exe will be in the `release` folder.

(Note: I also upgraded Cython to the latest version 0.29.30, it might have helped as well)